# Polite way to say "I'll let you know" to work colleague?

Tags: gramática

What is a polite but somewhat casual way to say "I'll let you know" or "let me get back to you", or something along those lines while I confirm something before letting them know, to a work colleague?

Comment: Yo lo haré saber

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He escuchado estas dos opciones:

```
te lo haré saber

te lo contaré
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use the verb 'avisar':

Te aviso yo.

Note the informal use of the present tense with a future meaning. If you were to use the future tense, it would feel more formal (e.g. 'Lo/le avisaremos cuando recibamos el producto').

And (at least in my variety of Spanish) it sounds a bit more casual with an initial 'ya':

Ya te aviso yo.

You can add additional information after it, like '(Ya) te aviso (yo) en cuanto lo sepa', '(ya) te aviso (yo) cuando me digan algo', etc.

Comment: Doesn't avisar mean to warn? Is a verb like informar not appropriate here?

Comment: No, 'avisar' is like 'let know' in English (although it is true that it is often mistranslated as 'warn'). The verb you want for 'warn' is 'advertir'. Compare: 'Me han advertido de que me podrían despedir' = 'They've warned me that they might fire me' and 'Me han avisado de que me van a subir el sueldo' = 'They've told me they're gonna raise my salary'. The verb 'informar', on the other hand, is formal, like 'inform' in English. You wouldn't usually say it when talking to a friend or a close colleague at work.

Answer (score 0):

También se puede decir de manera educada y al mismo tiempo informal;

- ¡Ya te informo!
- ¡Ya te digo! (se sobreentiende que es algo sobre el asunto)
- ¡Ya te cuento!
- ¡Hablamos! (se sobreentiende el ya, ya hablamos sobre el asunto)
- ¡Lo hablamos más adelante!
- ¡Ya lo vamos vi e n d o! (se sobreentiende que cuando se sucedan novedades, se irán tratando)